# Firebase query with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query a database with this structure.

[image]

This is my query so far:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('works');
    itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log('snap', snapshot);
        console.log('val', snapshot.val());
        let items = snapshot.val();
        let newState = [];
        console.log('tu ', items);
        for (let item in items) {
            console.log(item);
            newState.push({
                id: item,
                title: items[item].title,
                user: items[item].user
            });
        }
        this.setState({
            items: newState
        });
    });
}
```

I know it's wrong, because it returns null. How do I make it correct? I was following a tutorial earlier, but this is a little more complex then a todo list. I want to list the `works`.

This is the console response:

```
snap Object { node_: {…}, ref_: {…}, index_: {} } questions.js:17
val null questions.js:18
tu  null questions.js:21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('works');
```

into this:

```
const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('Works');
```

since you have works as capital letter.